# Why using unique_ptr with arrays causes compilation error?

Tags: c++, arrays, unique-ptr

Why using `unique_ptr <string> items;` instead of raw pointer `string *items;` throwing compilation error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class myarray
{
  private:
    unique_ptr <string> items;
    //string *items;
  public:
    myarray (int size=20) : items (new string [size] ) {}

    string& operator[] (const int index)
    {
      return items[index];
    }
};


int main()
{
  myarray m1(200);
  myarray m2;
  m1[19] = "test";
  cout << m1[19];
  return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
subscript2.cpp: In member function ‘std::string& myarray::operator[](int)’:
subscript2.cpp:15: error: no match for ‘operator[]’ in ‘((myarray*)this)->myarray::items[index]’
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a `unique_ptr` pointer to a dynamically allocated *array* of strings, you may want to use the `unique_ptr<T[]>` form, i.e.:

```
unique_ptr<string[]> items;
```

In fact:

- `unique_ptr<T>` is a pointer to a *single instance* of `T`
- `unique_ptr<T[]>` is a pointer to an *array* of `T`s

Answer (score 4):

If you need a `unique_ptr` to an array of strings then you need to declare it as:

```
unique_ptr <string[]> items;
```

Answer (score 2):

In the raw pointer case, you're fooling the compiler (and runtime) into thinking that `*items` is the zeroth element in an array of string objects. To use anything other than a zero value for `index` would be *undefined behaviour* even if you had allocated memory for the string. (`items[0]` is the same as `*items`.)

In using the `unique_ptr` version, the compiler is actually helping you.

If you want an array of strings then use `std::vector<std::string>` instead.